# Discord.py bot does not read when user @the bot

Tags: python, discord.py

I'm trying to make my Discord bot have a short interaction with users when greeting, but it seems to skip some code. I haven't been able to a solution so far.

Here is the part of the code I am having trouble with:

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
import os
import asyncio
import requests
import json
import random
from aiohttp import request
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
  await client.process_commands(message)
  if message.author == client.user:
    return

  username = str(message.author).split('#')[0]
  msg = message.content.lower()

  if message.content.startswith('greet'): #this is just to activate this part of code
    channel = message.channel
    await channel.send('Say my name!')
    def checkmessage(m):
      return m.content == '@Botty' and m.channel == channel #name of bot is Botty, but it can't detect this part, no error whatsoever.
    msg = await client.wait_for('message', check=checkmessage)
    await channel.send('Hi, {.author}!'.format(msg))
```

Any help is kindly appreciated, thank you!

Comment: Do you have any traceback you can provide? If you do, please edit your question to include it.

Comment: If by traceback you mean the error msg, thn no, nothing's showing on my end, the program does not seem to recognize the "@" function on discord?

Comment: Is everything else before your `checkmessage` working?

Comment: Yes, and when the message is not a "@" function(like just normal sentences/words) it could run the whole thing no problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you do a `@mention` to ping others on discord. The input **will become formatted** as `<@!{user-id-here}>`.

So, the discord python **will see** the message string as `<@!0123456789>` **not as** `@Botty`. You can verify it by using `print(message.content)`.

Alright, with your code:

```
def checkmessage(m):
      return m.content == '@Botty' and m.channel == channel
```

It certainly will not be able to recognize the `<@!0123456789>` string.

Hence, first, you have to use `client.user.id` to get the **user id of your bot**, and then **match it** instead of matching `@Botty`.

Ultimately, your code should looks like this:

```
def checkmessage(m):
      return m.content == f"<@!{client.user.id}>"  and m.channel == channel
```

This will allow the function to recognize `@mention`, hope this helps.

Comment: Not really what I meant, with the line I provided above, the code could work till the line" def checkmessage(m):".
I tried to replace "@Botty" with normal string sentences/words and the bot could give feedback "('Hi, {.author}!'.format(msg))" but I am looking to let ppl use @functions on discord and still be able to capture the message.(plz let me know if I need better explaining)

Comment: Hmm, I ran your provided code and it worked without problem. Just to make sure, you want the user to say `greet` first and then use `@Botty` to make the bot reply. Is that right?

Comment: Alright, I think I finally got what you meant. When you tried to use `@Botty` to call your bot, it will not work right? Assuming `Botty` is the real name of your bot, when you do `@mention` on discord, it became formatted. You only need to fix one line of your code, change `return m.content == '@Botty' and m.channel == channel` to `return m.content == f"<@!{client.user.id}>"  and m.channel == channel`. So that it recognize mentions.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of checking the content of the new message, just check if the bot was mentioned in the message. This can be done by checking if [`Client.user`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=mentions#discord.Client.user) is in the list [`Message.mentions`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Message.mentions):

```py
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    ...
    if message.content.startswith('greet'): #this is just to activate this part of code
        channel = message.channel
        await channel.send('Say my name!')
        def checkmessage(m):
            return client.user in m.mentions and m.channel == channel
        msg = await client.wait_for('message', check=checkmessage)
        await channel.send('Hi, {.author}!'.format(msg))
```

*On a side note, I would recommend checking out the [`discord.ext.commands`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/index.html) bot framework, rather than checking the contents of every message sent.*

Comment: Thanks for your edit on my question and your answer, although I prefer the other user's way of solving, your answer does give me a new perspective of coding my bot in the future, I will have better look at API reference later.
Thank you again!